# LoginFormAuthenticator::getUser()" method must return a UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

In an attempt to refactor entities from Class Table Inheritance to separate user type classes I've run into this:

> The "App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator::getUser()" method must
> return a UserInterface. You returned "array".

From the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#chain-user-provider) I configured a chain of user providers. I'm at a loss. For a custom user provider I've found Symfony's ChainUserProvider but integrating it into the process is not at all clear. `security.yaml` doesn't like including it either in `firewalls.main.provider` or anywhere in `providers.all_users`

Surely there's something else to add, but what and where?

security.yaml:

```
security:
    encoders:
      App\Entity\Admin:
            algorithm: auto
      App\Entity\Representative:
            algorithm: auto
      App\Entity\Volunteer:
            algorithm: auto
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN]
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        admin_provider:
            entity:
                class: 'App\Entity\Admin'
                property: email
        representative_provider:
            entity:
                class: 'App\Entity\Representative'
                property: email
        volunteer_provider:
            entity:
                class: 'App\Entity\Volunteer'
                property: email
        all_users:
            chain:
                providers: ['admin_provider', 'representative_provider', 'volunteer_provider']

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            provider: all_users
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
            anonymous: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path:   app_logout
                target: /
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and modified UserChecker:

```
use App\Entity\Admin;
use App\Entity\Representative;
use App\Entity\Volunteer;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{

    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof Admin && !$user instanceof Representative && !$user instanceof Volunteer) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof Admin && !$user instanceof Representative && !$user instanceof Volunteer) {
            return;
        }
...
}
```

and modified LoginFormAuthenticator:

```
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $admin = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Admin::class)->findBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
        $rep = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Representative::class)->findBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
        $vol = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Volunteer::class)->findBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        $user = $admin ?? $rep ?? $vol ?? null;
        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Credentials could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, Doctrine's `findBy` returns an array. So `$user = $admin ?? $rep ?? $vol ?? null;` will be assigned an array. Switch to `findOneBy` and see if it helps (at least I assume you only expect one user when searching by email).

Comment: Well, DOH! Another forest for the trees problem. You're absolutely correct - I missed that. Post as an answer & I'll accept. (PS - next up - guarantee unique email addresses).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is that the Doctrine Repository method [`findBy`](https://github.com/webmozart/doctrine-orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L177) returns an array, so your attempts to get the user here result with an array:

```
$admin = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Admin::class)->findBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
$rep = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Representative::class)->findBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
$vol = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Volunteer::class)->findBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

$user = $admin ?? $rep ?? $vol ?? null;
```

Since I assume you only expect one user when searching by email, you can substitute it with [`findOneBy`](https://github.com/webmozart/doctrine-orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L188), which returns an object or null.

Comment: I assume the down votes are because multiple user classes is a dumb idea. I get it. This was an experiment to see what it looks like. My eventual solution will likely be different.